# Valgrind reporting invalid read of memory inside alloc'd region

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm trying to use Valgrind to check for leaks inside my program.  It's found a few that were relatively easy to understand (invalid reads outside alloc'd regions), but I'm having trouble understanding this one.  What's the meaning of an invalid read that appears to be within the region of an alloc'd memory block?

```
==29445== Invalid read of size 32
==29445==    at 0x12BFB0: _mm256_load_si256 (avxintrin.h:910)
...
==29445==  Address 0x497e06e0 is 8,345,312 bytes inside a block of size 8,388,608 alloc'd
==29445==    at 0x52DB375: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:908)
```

What's meant by an invalid read of size 32 8345312 bytes within an 8388608-allocated block?  That seems to be within bounds?  Online research into Valgrind hasn't really helped me find other examples of this specific case (Valgrind reporting an invalid read that seems to be inside an alloc'd block)

My (maybe naive) expectation is that an invalid read "inside a block ... alloc'd" should only be triggered if an invalid read of size "read" for a block of size "size" starting at "byte" should only be triggered if: byte + read > size.  In this case byte=8345312, size=8388608, read=32: 8345312 + 32 < 8388608.

I don't really see anything else particularly suspicious about the SIMD load that could be triggering some sort of Valgrind issue here (eg. memory alignment issue on the load).  Is there some other case that can trigger the invalid read error?

Comment: It looks like this memory was allocated by memalign. What are the parameters of the memalign call ?  Possibly there is something fishy with the way the memalign replacement code handles big alignment requests.

Comment: The allocation was done via: void _mm_malloc(size, alignment) with size==8388608 and alignment==4096

Comment: ==21740==  Address 0x49655a60 is 8,346,208 bytes inside a block of size 8,388,608 alloc'd ==21740==    at 0x5150375: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:908)
 ==21740==    by 0x515043F: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1072)
 ==21740==    by 0x1291F7: _mm_malloc (mm_malloc.h:45)

Comment: I see no explanation from the provided arguments. I suggest to start your application so that it stops and wait for gdb+vgdb to connect. You can then use various monitor commands to see the status of the accessed memory location. First thing to do is to check if the address read is addressable. See https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands for more details

Comment: Of note, the allocation block is exactly 8Mbytes. The access is within that block, and it is 32 byte aligned. Is there a missing section saying that the memory was free'd?